# How to rewrite absolute assets paths on webserver subdirectory

Tags: html, .htaccess, assets, absolute-path

I'm using absolute paths to reference assets like css, images and javascript files. So in the `<head>` of `index.html` I have something like this:

```
<link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Assuming that my project directory looks like this:

```
- index.html
- assets/
-- css/
--- style.css
```

This works fine on my local webserver where I set the document root to this directory using a `<virtualhost>` directive. But when I put this on a webserver's subdirectory (e.g `http://www.example.com/subdirectory/`), it doesn't find the assets anymore when accessing `http://www.example.com/subdirectory/index.html`.

How can I solve that without having to use relative paths in `index.html`? Can it be achieved with an .htaccess file in the subdirectory? If yes, how?

## Edit

There are other folders on the webserver's root level, that shouldn't be affected by any redirect that occurs for `/subdirectory/`

Comment: /assets/css/style.css is a relative path, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @dave that's not true, it's absolute because it starts with a slash.

Comment: The solution is to use relative paths, in spite you don't like it.

Comment: It is true, it is relative to the document root.  An absolute path would include example.com.

Comment: You are right, actually it's a relative path I'm using (both /assets/ and assets/) are considered to be relative paths. But elsewhere, /assets/ is mentioned as best practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If *everything* is below `subdirectory`, you can use a simple rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
# don't rewrite, if it is already rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory
# only rewrite requests for files below /assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/assets/
RewriteRule ^.*$ /subdirectory/$0 [L]
```

Comment: this doesn't work. Browser still requesting http://www.example.com/assets/css/style.css

Comment: @mediafreakch It works in my test environment. Do you have the .htaccess in the root directory?

Comment: Ah, no I had placed it in /subdirectory . If I place it in the root directory it basically works. But now I understand what you meant by "everything is below subdirectory". It's not the case in my setup. There are many other directories that shouldn't be affected. How do I need to modify your solution to not affect the others?

Comment: @mediafreakch You can restrict the rule to `assets` for example. See updated answer.

Comment: Uhm..I hope the OP doesn't have an `assets/` directory within root ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in your head:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/subdirectory/">
```

Comment: That won't work , it would work if his urls were relative `assets/css/style.css` but they are absolute `/assets/css/style.css`

Comment: That is still relative. Look it up.